# Memory Issue with GetThumbnailsAsync

Tags: uwp, c++-winrt

**Minimal Example [C++/WinRT]:**

```cpp
#include "winrt/Windows.Storage.Streams.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Media.Editing.h"

using namespace std::literals;
using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::Media::Editing;
using namespace Windows::Storage;

int main()
{
    init_apartment();
    StorageFile file = StorageFile::GetFileFromPathAsync(L"video.mp4").get();
    MediaClip clip = MediaClip::CreateFromFileAsync(file).get();
    MediaComposition composition = MediaComposition();
    composition.Clips().Append(clip);

    while (true)
    {
        auto stream = composition.GetThumbnailAsync(0s, 10, 10, VideoFramePrecision::NearestFrame).get();
        printf("%lld\n", stream.Size());
    }
}
```

**Issue:** When I run this code, the memory usage rapidly increases and eventually the program fails. Ideally, I would assume that if I get the result of an operation, that operation stops consuming memory but in this case `GetThumbnailAsync` continues to use memory. Closing the operation or closing the result of the operation doesn't help. How can I make the `GetThumbnailAsync` operation release all the allocated memory after it's completed?

**Platform:** Microsoft Windows 10 Insider Preview (Build 17682)

Comment: The code in question doesn't appear to be leaking any resources. `GetThumbnailAsync(...).get()` returns a temporary, that is never assigned, and ought to get destroyed immediately. Just to verify this, can you single-step through the code, and make sure that this is what's actually happening? I believe there should be a call to `IUnknown::Release` somewhere. Check to see if this does in fact return 0.

Comment: @IInspectable The result of `GetThumbnailAsync(...).get()` is an `ImageStream` of size 10 by 10, so even if it is not immediately destroyed, it can't increase the memory consumption so fast (Code consumes 10GB of memory before it fails). So I'm assuming there is something internal to the `GetThumbnailsAsync` that uses a lot of memory but doesn't get destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for the repro. What Insider build are you seeing this on? I tested this on 17713 and I don't see a memory leak. It may be that this has already been fixed.

Comment: My Insider Build is 17682. I can install 17713 and try again.

Comment: I updated my Insider Build to 17692 and everything looks good now. I guess this was fixed in a recent patch.

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Comment: @Transcendental Can you add an answer with this conclusion and close this question please?